# Trouble identifying & capturing text with regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I've looked around on the stackoverflow and with google, but cannot find the specific answer I am looking for. And with regex, I am assuming because it is quite specific, and I am not sure what it is I am getting incorrect.

I am trying to capture 7 sets of strings in one long text string. I can capture 6, however I cannot tweak the regex enough to capture the 7th string.

The 7 groups I am trying to capture in the text below: **perks, currency, campaign, tabs, pore, urls, locale**

```
     text = 'gon.urls={stringstuffhere};gon.pageview={morstrings};gon.pore{stringstuffhere};
gon.capture={allyourstrings};
    gon.perks={stringshere};gon.base={stringsbelongtous};gon.campaign={evenmorestrings};gon.haha={somanystrings};
        gon.tabs=[{morestrings}{morestrings}{more strings}];
            gon.main={mainstringsturnon};gon.currency={strings};
    gon.locale="en";gon.default_later="somestrings"'
```

some notes about the string being searched

- each portion that I am trying to search starts with "gon.*title*"
- All of the formatting of the text above is accurate in terms of the 'gon.*title*', '=', and brackets/curly brackets (or not). The only difference of the actual text, is the text inside these brackets/parentheses.
- The text of what I am capturing varies in size, and includes all kinds of text, including alphanumeric, white space and non-whitespace characters
- **Most of the portions I am searching for a sandwiched between other 'gon' strings that I am not capturing, with the exception of the 'locale' group that is directly after another captured group.**
- One of the strings I am searching for (gon.tabs) starts with a bracket '[', the others (aside from locale) start with a {
- each string has a semi colon after each 'gon' portion, starting the the next 'gon' group
- All of the formatting of the text above is accurate in terms of the 'gon.*title*', '=', and brackets/curly brackets (or not). The only difference of the actual text, is the text inside these brackets/parentheses.
- **'gon.locale' is the portion that goes missing**

My approach so far has been to find the portions that have 'gon.*title*, the '=' sign and possible a '[' or '{', then capture the text I'd like, and end with possibly a '}' or ']' followed by a ';'.

This is the pattern I am using to capture the data currently:

```
result= re.findall('gon.(perks|currency|campaign|tabs|pore|urls|locale)=\[?\{?(.*?)\"?\}?\]?;', text)
```

This captures all 7, but, it does not capture *all* of one of the strings due to a semi-colon being in the text being captured. (the text has the ability to have unknown amount of semi colons).

output is something like this:

```
[('urls',
  'stringstuffhere'),
 ('pore',
  'stringstu')...]  #rest of the groups are captured correctly, but off from a semi colon in the string
```

I tried adjusting the pattern to this:

```
result= re.findall('gon.(perks|currency_exchange|campaign|tabs|trust_passport|urls|locale)=\[?\{?(.*?)\"?\}?\]?;gon', text)
```

adding the 'gon' of the next 'group' of text. This helps capture all of the portion I was missing, however, it does **not** find/capture the 'gon.locale' string.

output is something like this:

```
[('urls',
      'stringstuffhere'),
     ('pore',
      'stringstuffhere'),
('tabs',
      '{morestrings}{morestrings}{more strings}'),
('campaign',
      'evenmorestrings'),
('perks',
      'stringshere'),
('currency',
      'strings'),
('pore',
      'stringstuffhere')]  #locale group  missing
```

I've tried a variety of different options tweaks, including using raw strings. But it's either I miss some of the data in one the string groups and capture the 7th string, or, I miss one of the string groups, but capture all of the data in the groups that I do find.

The desired result would be similar to the most recent example above, but with the missing 'locale' group. I don't know why adding a 'g' or 'gon' to the end of the pattern would make that portion fall off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
If I can clarify the explanation above, please let me know.

**** Made an edit. When building with the https://regex101.com/ tool. I saw that the last 'locale' group was directly after another group that I was capturing. Thus, when searching the string, adding the 'g' to the end of the pattern help capture all of the string I was missing, but 'pointer' doesn't include that 'g' again for the next group, but starts at the next letter 'o'.

I found two options to work, adding another pattern starting with 'on' for the 'locale' group, or using a positive lookahead that matches the next 'gon' string without making it part of the match. Two patterns below.

```
r'(?<=gon\.)(perks|currency|campaign|tabs|pore|urls|locale)\[?{?\"?(.+?)\"?}?\]?;(?=g)|on\.(locale)=(\"\w+\");', html)

r'gon.(perks|currency|campaign|tabs|pore|urls|locale)=\[?\{?(.*?\"?)\}?\]?;(?=gon)'
```

Comment: Where does that string come from? Surely it represents some sort of data format, right? Also, a tool I find very useful when dealing with regex is https://regex101.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe,

`gon\.(perks|currency|campaign|tabs|trust_passport|urls|locale)=\[?{?"?(.*?)"?}?\]?;|gon\.pore{([^}]+)}`

or,

`gon\.(perks|currency|campaign|tabs|trust_passport|urls|locale|pore)=?\[?{?"?(.*?)"?}?\]?;`

would be working here just OK.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OM3WwP/1/)

#### Test 1

```
import re

string = '''
gon.urls={stringstuffhere};gon.pageview={morstrings};gon.pore{stringstuffhere};
gon.capture={allyourstrings};
    gon.perks={stringshere};gon.base={stringsbelongtous};gon.campaign={evenmorestrings};gon.haha={somanystrings};
        gon.tabs=[{morestrings}{morestrings}{more strings}];
            gon.main={mainstringsturnon};gon.currency={strings};gon.bub={someonesetusup};
    gon.locale="en";gon.default_later="somestrings
'''

expression = r'(?m)gon\.(perks|currency|campaign|tabs|trust_passport|urls|locale)=\[?{?"?(.*?)"?}?\]?;|gon\.pore{([^}]+)}'


print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output 1

> [('urls', 'stringstuffhere', ''), ('', '', 'stringstuffhere'),
>   ('perks', 'stringshere', ''), ('campaign', 'evenmorestrings', ''),
>   ('tabs', 'morestrings}{morestrings}{more strings', ''), ('currency',
>   'strings', ''), ('locale', 'en', '')]

#### Test 2

```
import re

string = '''
gon.urls={stringstuffhere};gon.pageview={morstrings};gon.pore{stringstuffhere};
gon.capture={allyourstrings};
    gon.perks={stringshere};gon.base={stringsbelongtous};gon.campaign={evenmorestrings};gon.haha={somanystrings};
        gon.tabs=[{morestrings}{morestrings}{more strings}];
            gon.main={mainstringsturnon};gon.currency={strings};gon.bub={someonesetusup};
    gon.locale="en";gon.default_later="somestrings
'''

expression = r'(?m)gon\.(perks|currency|campaign|tabs|trust_passport|urls|locale|pore)=?\[?{?"?(.*?)"?}?\]?;'


print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output 2

> [('urls', 'stringstuffhere'), ('pore', 'stringstuffhere'), ('perks',
>   'stringshere'), ('campaign', 'evenmorestrings'), ('tabs',
>   'morestrings}{morestrings}{more strings'), ('currency', 'strings'),
>   ('locale', 'en')]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QwAqz4/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/QwAqz4/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the examples. Unfortunately, those two examples are 'getting stuck' in the same spot as my original pattern. The pattern where it stops working is with text like this: '"text here”. \\n&#x2028;More text that needs to be captured.."'' That is the original text, and what gets captured is this portion: ' 'text here”. \\n&#x2028'. Thank you for the links! I'll try playing around with those resources, much appreciated!

Comment: 'gon\.(perks|currency|campaign|tabs|pore|urls)=\[?{?\"?(.+?)\"?}?\]?;+?g|on\.(locale)=(\"\w+\");' seems to work! But, I have a lot of zero length matches. I need to try and adjust a bit to tidy that up. Thanks! Through one of your resources, I saw that the 'locale' group actually comes after another capturing group. Because the 'g' is in the first pattern, it never catches the g for the 'locale' pattern, so I switched to 'on', which captures the group.

Comment: i found the solution without introducing zero-length matches. It was my second example in the original ask, but with putting the 'gon' at the end as a look ahead assertion. 'gon.(perks|currency_exchange|campaign|tabs|trust_passport|urls|locale)=\[?\{?(.*?)\"?\}?\]?;(?=gon)'. Thank you for your help!!